# Distinct combination of value for a specific path

Tags: xquery, basex

I've a XML tree where each node has one child. As show [here](https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Ym/5).

Is there a way to find the distinct combination of values related to a specific path?

For example if consider the tree in the previous example, I would like to find all the different combinations of tag based on their values:

```
INPUT: /A/C/D
<A value="5.4"><C value="1.7"><D value="0.4"></D></C></A>
<A value="5.1"><C value="1.4"><D value="0.2"></D></C></A>
<A value="5.1"><C value="1.4"><D value="0.4"></D></C></A>
<A value="5.0"><C value="1.4"><D value="0.2"></D></C></A>
<A value="5.0"><C value="1.5"><D value="0.2"></D></C></A>
<A value="4.9"><C value="1.5"><D value="0.1"></D></C></A>
<A value="4.6"><C value="1.5"><D value="0.2"></D></C></A>
<A value="4.6"><C value="1.4"><D value="0.3"></D></C></A>
<A value="4.4"><C value="1.4"><D value="0.2"></D></C></A>

INPUT: /C/D
<C value="1.4"><D value="0.2"></D></C>
<C value="1.4"><D value="0.3"></D></C>
<C value="1.4"><D value="0.4"></D></C>
<C value="1.5"><D value="0.1"></D></C>
<C value="1.5"><D value="0.2"></D></C>
<C value="1.7"><D value="0.4"></D></C>
```

Comment: What kind of "path" semantics do you have in mind? XQuery is based on XPath and in your linked sample for instance the XPath `/A/C/D` doesn't select anything, even taking the `root` element into account: https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nqn5Ym/6

Comment: The input in the example is a simple string. You're right when you say that if you pass this to xpath, I don't get an output. But I don't know how I can do it and the type of path. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
distinct-values(
   A//C//D/string-join(
     ancestor-or-self::*[self::A|self::C|self::D]/@value, '|'))
```

Comment: Many thanks! I adapted the code for the different paths and solved my problem.